# Example of code implemented using state machine versus procedural

Tags: state-machine, procedural-programming

I am curious about when one would use state machines (Event-driven) versus procedural paradigm. Any useful program takes some input(s), and then delivers some output(s). With some googling, it seems like common examples for state machines are for parsers or low level embedded devices, where as procedural is for all sorts of things, but I still am struggling to understand how different they would actually be for certain applications. Would it be possible for someone to demonstrate state machines usefulness with code written in that paradigm versus standard procedural?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: This is also far too broad for the site. You should come here with a very specific, practical question about programming, along with the actual code you're having difficulty with.

Comment: Also state machines are not necessarily event driven. In fact they can be orthogonal. You could easily write a state machine that is not event driven and an event driven application that is not a state machine.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I am relatively new to the idea of programming paradigms so forgive me if my question is unwarranted. In an attempt to wrap my head around the usefulness of a state machine, I thought an example of a common coding paradigm like procedural versus writing the same code in a state machine fashion would help prove its usefulness.

Comment: I'm sorry to slam you so hard. This site works so well because it does have strict standards for the questions.

Comment: A classic example for a state machine would be a traffic light. Try implementing one of those. If you get stuck come here and post your code. We'll help you fix it no problem.

Comment: It's okay, I understand. Would it be inappropriate for me to post code of a functioning procedural version of a traffic light and a state machine version and then ask what the advantages are? Will it be obvious by then? Thinking about it now, it seems like a state machine would be the same thing since it's essentially just a loop with some conditional statements.

Comment: Asking about the advantages would be a primarily opinion-based question. It's also off-topic. You need to learn off-site and then come here with a specific and practical programming problem.